# Navigation from one viewcontroller to next using edgePanning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and not aware of lot of features which iOS provides so need your help in building new UI.

Now my requirement is I have  A - B - C three controllers where B is homescreen,  I want user to pan (pan I mean to say next view controller should come w.r.t to users finger touch ) on the right edge or left edge to go to their respective ViewControllers from B and can come back 
along the same line ..

This is my basic structure, I know how to do it with the swipe but then it is wont fulfill my requirment , also to slide the new screen w.r.t to finger is also there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SWReavelViewController. It is a very easy to use component and will be suited for your solution.

You can find the code [HERE](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

Answer (score 0):

you could get your hands on ViewDeck. It got some more offering than SWReavelViewController. Check this [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). If anything else is there let me know.